# MySQL: "recursive" update rows. EMA Example

Tags: mysql, recursion

The general question is how to update column_A on row n, which depend on column_A on row n-1.

The specific question is compute and persist EMA (exponential moving average) is a MYSQL table.

for EMA calculation (for 10% or 19-day EMA), EMA(n) = 0.1 * price + 0.9 EMA(n-1)
So, we have a recursive equation where the value of row n depend on the value row (n-1)

In any programming language, this is easy to compute.
But if EMA is stored as a column in a MYSQL table.  How one can compute and update EMA column efficiently in MYSQL script?  Right now, I can only do a sequential update in a loop.  My ugly solution is listed here.  It requires order(n) updates.

Any smart ideas that only need order(1) update?

Thank you very much

---

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS update_ema$$

CREATE PROCEDURE update_ema(
IN series_id INT
)
BEGIN

DECLARE counter INT;

SET counter = 2;

WHILE counter <= 5000 DO

    update price_table as x
    inner join  price_table y 
    on x.id = y.id and x.row_num = y.row_num+1 
    and x.Id=series_id and x.row_num = counter
    set x.EMA19 = func_ema(19, y.EMA19, x.price);

SET counter = counter + 1;


END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value of column_a, row(n) depends on the value of column_a, row(n-1), then changing it will change the value in all following rows:

(not code)

```
if

x = row number
row(x) col(a) = f(row(x-1) col(a))


then

where x = n
row(n) col(a) = f(row(n-1) col(a))

where x = n + 1
row((n+1)) col(a) = f(row((n+1)-1) col(a))
row(n+1) col(a) = f(row(n) col(a))
```

When you change n, you have to update n+1, which goes on until the end of the table. I don't believe you can get much better than what you have.